# Is it better to calculate x-1 into a variable and then use that?

Tags: c++, optimization

Is it better to calculate x-1 into a variable and then use that?

I have a for loop and inside (x-1). Is it better to create
new variable y=x-1, and then use y inside the loop, rather
then recalculate it many times in the for loop? I will save 
many subtractions. Not sure if this is some optimization?

Comment: This optimization is called [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) and is one of many standard optimizations that modern compilers implement.

Answer (score 5):

Don't under or over estimate the capabilities of the compiler.

Profile first.

Look at the assembly language listing of the optimized version for the function.
The compiler may be able to combine the X-1 with another instruction.

Wait until the code works completely and is robust before making optimizations.  Often times, code is harder to debug when it is optimized and you could be wasting your time optimizing code that isn't used frequently.

Answer (score 3):

If `x` does not change inside the loop, then the compiler will most likely optimize it and calculate it only once, so it should not matter.  (Of course, if `x` does change inside the loop, then it goes without saying that you should recompute it inside the loop).

Aside from the optimization aspect, it is probably more important to write the code so it makes the most sense to another programmer (e.g., someone maintaining the code).  If using `x-1` inside the loop makes the code clearer, it is almost certainly better to write it that way.  Unless the loop is extremely critical to overall performance, it is (in my opinion) better to focus on making the code easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that will help speed up your code.  Anything that decreases the number of calculations you need to perform will increase the speed of your code, especially if your loop goes through a lot of iterations.

No need to do something over and over again if you can do it just once :)

This is assuming that `x` doesn't change during your loop, though.  If `x` does change, then you'll need to recalculate it because `y` will be different each time through the loop.

Comment: The compiler may optimize this instruction and calculate it once anyway or use it in such a way it adds very little to the performance time.